# Importing array list in text file into Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, txt

I have an array list in a txt file like:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

I would like to get this data into an array in my python code. Afterall, when I print it in Python I should see below output:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

(Exactly same with content in txt.)

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: If that's your text file you could just use `json.load()`

Comment: Do you know how to open and read the contents of a file? If not, that's where you should start.

Comment: Yes, sorry actually I forgot to mention, I load the file but couldn't complete the code. Now it is solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To read the data from your txt file and store it as a list in Python, you can use the following code:

```
with open('path/to/your/file.txt', 'r') as file: data = file.read()
myList = data.split()
```

Comment: I tried following because of encoding error and it worked: with open('sozluk.txt', encoding="utf8") as f:
    content = f.read()

Comment: This produces a string, not a list.

Comment: You're right, I added the .split() function @Karl Knechtel.